# find value (-2)^-(2)^(-2)

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

> Find the value of $(-2)^{-(2)^{(-2)}}$. Is it 16/8/-8/none?

My attempt: $a^{-x}=\frac1{a^x}$, so, $(-2)^{-(2)^{(-2)}}=(-2)^{\frac{-1}{2^2}}=\frac{1}{(-2)^{\frac14}}$. That is, I would pick 'none of the given options' as my answer.

But it is given that answer is 16. And the comments below also suggest that the correct answer is indeed 16. So I will appreciate if one can tell the mistake in my solution.

EDIT: I've cross-checked. The statement that I have posed is same as was asked in the exam. No parsing error by me. Maybe by the question-setter, don't know.

Comment: $-(2)^{-2} = -0.25$, 
$(-2)^{-0.25}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{(-2)}}$. Maybe there's a formatting error, and the base on the 'second level' should be $-2$, not just $2$ ?

Comment: $16$ would be the correct answer for $\left((-2)^{-2}\right)^{-2}$.

Comment: @Ramit, I think it should be  $\left((-2)^{(-2)}\right)^{-2}=(-2)^{(-2)(-2)}=(-2)^4=16$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee- edited.

Comment: _If_ there is a mistake in your solution, it's at the very beginning, and you mis-parsed the expression. If the expression was $\left((-2)^{(-2)}\right)^{(-2)}$, the solution is $16$. If the expression was what you wrote, $(-2)^{-2^{(-2)}}$, that's indeed none of the offered options.

Comment: If you're asking for the value of $(-2)^{-(2)^{(-2)}}$, that will involve complex numbers. Do you want the value of $(-2)^{-(2)^{(-2)}}$ or the value of $(-2)^{(-2)^{(-2)}}$?

Comment: @bluesh34- it's the former.

Comment: I'd check it with your teacher/lecturer: the question seems a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @bluesh34- I too would like to meet the question-setter or atleast somebody who printed the page.

Comment: No, it was an entrance test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you may have confused/misread the problem statement:

$$(-2)^{-(2)^{(-2)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{(-2)}}\quad \neq \quad\left((-2)^{-2}\right)^{-2} = (-2)^{-2\cdot -2} = (-2)^4 = 16$$

That is, we need to be careful to note where the negation of an exponent occurs $(-2)^{a} \neq -(2^{a})$, and we need to be careful to disambiguate $(a^b)^c$ from $a^{(b^c)}.$

EDIT:

If the problem you posted is **precisely** what appears on the practice exam, then you've correctly argued that none of the given answers are correct. In that case, indeed, there must have been a parsing error in the source, if indeed the answer were to be $16$.

Comment: So maybe there indeed is an error in printing the question.

Comment: That's what I'm guessing. Was the source printed on-line, or in a booklet?

Comment: It is a booklet.

Comment: Those kinds of printing errors can cause prospective test-takers a lot of misery and second-guessing!

Comment: and a lot of time too. Phew!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice clarifications! +1